# Read p7m file in xamarin for android and iOS using mimekit

Tags: android, xamarin, bouncycastle, smime, mimekit

I am trying to decrypt a .P7M file for Android in Xamarin android using bouncycastle and mimekit. When I hit
            "ApplicationPkcs7Mime p7m = new ApplicationPkcs7Mime(SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData, ms)";

The Android emulator does not know how to call it from the Android cert store or the USB card reader.

```
       public class CustomBouncyCastleSecureMimeContext : BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext
      {
          public CustomBouncyCastleSecureMimeContext() : base()
          {
          }}
```

Updated code

```
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Inside DecryptMime");
        CryptographyContext.Register(typeof(BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext));
        // Payload from the add-in contains the mime content of the email on base-64 encoding   

        byte[] bytes = ResourceLoader.GetEmbeddedResourceBytes(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ResourceLoader)), "smime.p7m");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        ApplicationPkcs7Mime p7m = new ApplicationPkcs7Mime(SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData, ms);

        // parse data as cms enveloped
        CmsEnvelopedDataParser edParser = new CmsEnvelopedDataParser(bytes);

        // reiterate inside to find recipient info
        ICollection collections = edParser.GetRecipientInfos().GetRecipients();
        IEnumerator it = collections.GetEnumerator();
        while (it.MoveNext())
        {
            RecipientInformation info = (RecipientInformation)it.Current;
        }
```

Does anyone have experience in reading a P7M file in android?

Many Thank

Comment: try to add `CryptographyContext.Register` before `ApplicationPkcs7Mime p7m = new ApplicationPkcs7Mime(SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData, ms);`

Comment: I added CryptographyContext.Register(typeof(BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext)); and extend the class but dosent seem to work

Comment: BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext is abstract so registering that class will fail. You need to register your custom subclass.

Comment: `p7m = new ApplicationPkcs7Mime(SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData, ms)` does not depend on you registering any S/MIME context, so I am not sure why you are getting an exception on that line anyway seeing as how it doesn't do any cryptography at all. All it does is create a MIME object to wrap the already-encrypted data stream.